# Setting the x axis position to y = 0 in MPAndroid Bar Chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I've been struggling with this for a while now, but I can't find a way to have an x axis, with its labels, lie at the position y = 0. This is important when I have both positive and negative values- I don't want to put the axis at the defaults given by AndroidMPChart (TOP, BOTTOM, BOTH_SIDED, TOP_INSIDE, BOTTOM_INSIDE), as none of these apply.

I have managed to edit the xAxisRenderer, and have been able to pass the ratio of my maxY value to my minY value, hoping to manually find the position to set the axis. The issue with this, however, is that I need the position of the highest Y bar and lowest Y bar. I can find the position of the lowest Y bar no problem, using mViewPortHandler.contentBottom(), but using
mViewPortHandler.contentTop() does not give me the top of the Y bar for some reason.

```
List<Float> floatList = new ArrayList<>();
floatList.add(0f);
floatList.add(mViewPortHandler.contentTop());
floatList.add(mViewPortHandler.offsetTop()+mViewPortHandler.getScaleY());
floatList.add(mViewPortHandler.getContentCenter().y);
floatList.add(mViewPortHandler.contentBottom());
floatList.add(mViewPortHandler.getChartHeight());

if (mDebug) {         
  for (int i=0; i<floatList.size(); i++) {                    
    Paint paint = new Paint(); 
    paint.setColor(getRandomColorInColorFormPrintString("i = " + i));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    c.drawLine(mViewPortHandler.contentLeft()+15*i,
    floatList.get(i), mViewPortHandler.contentRight()+15*i,  
    floatList.get(i), paint); 
  }        
}
```

Notice how contentBottom (yellow) nails the bottom of the bar, but content top and offset top (pink/red) are not accurate in finding the top of the content. I've tried this with many different values, contentBottom is consistently accurate, whereas contentTop/offsetTop are not, and are not offset by the height of the value label (I already tried this as well).
[image]

All I really need is a dynamic way to set the position of the x axis right between positive and negative values. I am so surprised that this option doesn't come with Android MP Charts. If it does, please let me know if I am overcomplicating things.
If there is no way to set this through Android MP Charts, please let me know if you know what I'm doing wrong in trying to get the top of the Y bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem--

in the renderAxisLine function =>

```
MPPointD pos = mTrans.getPixelForValues(0f, 0f);
c.drawLine(mViewPortHandler.contentLeft(),
                (float)pos.y, mViewPortHandler.contentRight(),
                (float)pos.y, mAxisLinePaint);
```